Electric field on conducting and insulating plate using Gaussian Surfaces
I am in AP Physics E&M and have learned how to find electric field strengths using Gaussian surfaces for static charges, however I cannot understand why the field produced by an insulating plate is half of that produced by a conducting one.
Also, in the example, we are only considering surface charge density, so in theory, it shouldn't matter whether or not the material is a conductor or insulator.
However as the lesson goes, we have an infinite connecting plate (to ignore side effects) and we use both end-caps of a Gaussian Pillbox shape, corresponding to the 2A seen in the bottom equation (see option 2):

However when we try the same experiment on an insulating plate, apparently we only consider one end-cap of the Gaussian surface and thus only use A in the bottom equation, leading to half the the field strength as a conducting plate with the same charge.

Can someone explain to me why this happens?


In case of insulating plate, we assume the charge distributed throughout the material to reside on one surface with surface charge density sigma. This is how surface charge density is defined for insulating plate.
But in case of conductor, there is no charge inside the conductor and hence we treat the charge densities on both surfaces differently.
So, when we distribute a charge of Q uniformly on a insulating sheet let the surface charge density turns out to be X.
When the same charge is distributed on a conducting sheet, the surface charge density is X/2 because the charge is distributed between the 2 surfaces.
So, in the case you mentioned, there is actually twice the charge on the conducting sheet than the insulating sheet, since surface charge density is equal in both. So, twice field is produced by the conductor.
It is actually a matter about how surface charge density is defined in case of the insulating sheet.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
